# Где ошибка в скрипте вкладок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tab, tabs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка в скрипте? Благодарю!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".tab_container").hide();
  $(".tabs_title:first").addClass("tabs_title_active").show();
  $(".tab_container:first").show();

  $(".tabs_title").click(function() {
    $(".tabs_title").removeClass("tabs_title_active");
    $(this).addClass("tabs_title_active");
    $(".tab_container").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_titles">
  <a href="#tab_container_1" class="tabs_title">1</a>
  <a href="#tab_container_2" class="tabs_title">2</a>
  <a href="#tab_container_3" class="tabs_title">3</a>
</div>

<div id="tab_container_1" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 1
</div>
<div id="tab_container_2" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 2
</div>
<div id="tab_container_3" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 3
</div>
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то?

Comment: Если проблема в том, что табы не переключаются, то потому что `$(this).find("a").attr("href") === undefined`, так как `$(this)` и есть "нужная ссылка". `$(this).find("a").attr("href")` -> `$(this).attr("href")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` указывет на элемент `a`, поэтому не нужно выполнять его поиск

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".tab_container").hide();
  $(".tabs_title:first").addClass("tabs_title_active").show();
  $(".tab_container:first").show();

  $(".tabs_title").click(function() {
    $(".tabs_title").removeClass("tabs_title_active");
    $(this).addClass("tabs_title_active");
    $(".tab_container").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_titles">
  <a href="#tab_container_1" class="tabs_title">1</a>
  <a href="#tab_container_2" class="tabs_title">2</a>
  <a href="#tab_container_3" class="tabs_title">3</a>
</div>

<div id="tab_container_1" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 1
</div>
<div id="tab_container_2" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 2
</div>
<div id="tab_container_3" class="tab_container">
  Текст вкладки 3
</div>
```